# curl with SPNEGO fails when using an IP address instead of a fqdn: An unsupported mechanism was requested

Tags: curl, kerberos, spnego

I'm running a Spring app which supports API with Kerberos authentication.

When using fqdn, the api is called successfully:

```
$ curl -vvv -u : --negotiate "http://TARGET_HOSTNAME:PORT/api/v1/configuration"
*   Trying TARGET_IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to TARGET_HOSTNAME (TARGET_IP) port PORT (#0)
* Server auth using Negotiate with user ''
> GET /api/v1/configuration HTTP/1.1
> Host: TARGET_HOSTNAME:PORT
> Authorization: Negotiate XXXX
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate XXXX; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 17:34:52 GMT
<
{
  "msg" : "Ok",
  "result" : [ {
    "threshold" : 50
  } ]
* Connection #0 to host TARGET_HOSTNAME left intact
}* Closing connection 0
```

However, when trying to call this same API with ip address, it fails:

```
$ curl -vvv -u : --negotiate "http://TARGET_IP:PORT/api/v1/configuration"
*   Trying TARGET_IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to TARGET_IP (TARGET_IP) port PORT (#0)
* gss_init_sec_context() failed:  An unsupported mechanism was requested. unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown.
* Connection #0 to host TARGET_IP left intact
curl: (67) Login denied
* Closing connection 0
```

What would be the reason for this problem?

When calling APIs that don't require Kerberos authentication, both with fqdn and with ip address are done well.

klist command shows as:

```
$ klist -5
Credentials cache: API:XXX
        Principal: USERNAME@REALM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Oct 26 01:48:41 2021  Oct 26 04:48:39 2021  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
Oct 26 02:27:05 2021  Oct 26 04:48:39 2021  HTTP/TARGET_HOST@REALM
```

Any comment or link appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was the keytab problem.

I'm not sure whether I'm explaining exactly, but this is how I understood.

When sending a Spnego request, a client specifies a SPN.

In this case, SPNs were `TARGET_HOST@REALM` and `TARGET_IP@REALM`.

And the server who handles this request, the Spring app, should have a keytab which has all these SPNs.

But I found that the keytab only had a principal of `TARGET_HOST`.

Something like this:

```
$ klist -kt /path/to/keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/path/to/keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 02/03/20 14:33:39 HTTP/TARGET_HOST@REALM
   3 02/03/20 14:33:39 HTTP/TARGET_HOST@REALM
```

That should contain `HTTP/TARGET_IP@REALM`.

To implement this, the following steps were done:

- Create a new principal with `HTTP/TARGET_IP@REALM`
- Create a new keytab which has the new principal
- Merge the existing and the new keytab

Then, it shows as:

```
$ klist -kt /path/to/keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/path/to/keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 02/03/20 14:33:39 HTTP/TARGET_HOST@REALM
   3 02/03/20 14:33:39 HTTP/TARGET_HOST@REALM
   1 02/03/20 14:33:39 HTTP/TARGET_IP@REALM
```

Then I restarted the dispatcher app with the new keytab, which solved my problem.

Comment: I am quite surprised that it works: by default the Kerberos client _demands_ a canonical DNS name for the server, and does forward + reverse DNS lookups to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks. And in case you wonder: yes, Kerberos was designed long before load balancers, VIPs,  corporate traffic sniffers, etc. became common.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Unless the server has no rDNS at all, in which case the MIT/Heimdal Kerberos client _will_ just use the IP address for the SPN, according to last time I tried it. (Unlike the Windows Kerberos client, which neither canonicalizes names nor allows IP addresses.)